# How to extract the contents of square brackets in a string of text in c# using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, match

if i have a string of text like below, how can i collect the contents of the brackets in a collection in c# even if it goes over line breaks?

eg...

```
string s = "test [4df] test [5yu] test [6nf]";
```

should give me..

collection[0] = 4df

collection[1] = 5yu

collection[2] = 6nf

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with regular expressions, and a bit of Linq.

```
    string s = "test [4df] test [5y" + Environment.NewLine + "u] test [6nf]";

    ICollection<string> matches =
        Regex.Matches(s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""), @"\[([^]]*)\]")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToList();

    foreach (string match in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(match);
```

Output:

```
4df
5yu
6nf
```

Here's what the regular expression means:

```
\[   : Match a literal [
(    : Start a new group, match.Groups[1]
[^]] : Match any character except ]
*    : 0 or more of the above
)    : Close the group
\]   : Literal ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been playing about but unable to manage it - how would I change the regex so it was inclusive of brackets?

Comment: Took me a while reverse engineering that that helped to realise it is you accessing the second element in the match Groups[1] that gives you 4df etc rather than with the square brackets [4df] etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[[^\]]+\]", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: @"\[([^]]*)\]" seems to be a favorite pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to correctly escape the special characters used in regular expressions, for example you can match a `[` character this way: `@"\["`

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[.+?\]");
var collection = rx.Matches(s);
```

You will need to trim the square brackets off, the important part is the lazy operator.

Comment: Won't work over multiple lines, even if you specify RegexOptions.Multiline (I know, I tried ;))

Comment: Works accross multiples line fine for me

Comment: You could use Regex.SingleLine - this almost works except it captures the \n's too. In fact this would probably even perform slightly better performing than the solution I presented since it only needs to Replace on the captured parts of the string rather than the whole string.