# Regex to extract the content of a $(xxx) token in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string with several placeholder tokens like so:

```
"hello $(firstname) $(lastname), you're on StackOverflow!";
```

Simples :) I'm trying to write a regex that will look at a string like the above, and return all of the tokens which exist. For example in this case the return value should be `{ "firstname", "lastname" }`.

I'm a beginner with Regex, this is what I tried to write:

```
"\$\(.+?\)"
```

However the matches include the `$` and brackets, eg: `{ "$(firstname)", "$(lastname)" }`

How can I modify the regex so that it only returns the text inside the brackets? I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947596/extract-string-between-braces-using-regex-ie-content) for guidance but I cannot see how that regex works differently than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without grouping:

```
'(?<=\$\()[^)]+(?=\))'
```

test with grep:

```
kent$  grep -Po '(?<=\$\()[^)]+(?=\))' v 
firstname
lastname
```

or see it live here:  http://regexr.com?2vke8

Comment: This works great! Thank you :) I'd really like to understand what I did wrong in my regex, and what technique you used to make it work. DO you need to use lookahead/lookbehind for this?

Comment: @MattDavey Zero width assertions allow you to check some condition during matching, but not show the assertion in match result. I used lookahead and behind. Therefore the dollar '$' and '()' are not in result.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your regex to:

```
"\$\((.+?)\)"
```

The unescaped parentheses should indicate what you want to match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this but the result was the same as with my regex.

Comment: Revisiting this question some years later, and having a much better understanding of regular expressions, I can see that your answer was indeed helpful. +1!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
\$\(([^\)]*)
```

What language are you trying to use?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! On the input "$(a) $(b) $(c)", the result from this regex was { "$(a", "$(b", "$(c" }. I'm using C#

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
"\$\((?'val'.+?)\)"
```

and add the flag `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this but the result was the same as with my regex. (I tried it with explicit capture). Does this regex put the results into groups?