# Regular expression in C# to find matches like "x-[some_string]"

Tags: c#, regex

What is the Regular Expression in C# to find matches inside text 
that starting with "x-[" and ending with "]"?

I've tried something like this:

```
Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"^x-[.*]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Ive tried something like this:Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"^x-\[.*\]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: Your regex was perfect except you have to escape `[` and `]` because they have special meaning.. They are character class..

Comment: See [*How to extract the contents of square brackets in a string of text in c# using Regex*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811183/how-to-extract-the-contents-of-square-brackets-in-a-string-of-text-in-c-sharp-us). Easy to google.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
x-\[([^]]+)\]
# that is: look for x-[ literally
# capture and save anything that is not a ]
# followed by ]
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lM4nS2/1).

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
string input = "x-[ABCD]";
string pattern = "^x-\\[(.*)\\]$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

Match match = rgx.Match(input);

if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/s2mb89)**

**UPDATE**

As pointed by [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231450/jan), there will be too much backtracking in cases like `x-[ABCDEFGHJJHGHGFGHGFVFGHGFGHGFGHGGHGGHGDCNJK]ABCD]`. My updated `regex` is similar to his

```
^x-\[([^\]]*)\]$
```

Comment: It is very inefficient to match everything (`.*`) and then backtrace - better be precise in the first place!

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need a regex for it? Simple `String` operation should serve your purpose.

```
yourString.EndsWith("]");
yourString.StartsWith("x-[");
```

Comment: Its a big text and I need all the words that match this pattern

Comment: @Natali ok, then its better to use it.....

for the downvote: if you need to perform these operation on a single string, string operations gives you better performance...refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962670/regex-ismatch-vs-string-contains) link......thats why i suggested this one